# match random string between quotes Regex javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this bunch of text and I want to return **ma7jq2s9xgoy**

How do I return this 12 random code between the quotes as shown below?

```
rpcService=ma7jq2s9xgoy" class="picker-frame" name="ma7jq2s9xgoy" id="ma7jq2s9xgoy" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><div style="display: none;"
```

Comment: Take the id? ... `yourIframe.id === "ma7jq2s9xgoy"` Don't regex your html because reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really just the string and not the whole HTML set, you could do sth. like:

```
var string = 'rpcService=ma7jq2s9xgoy" class="picker-frame" name="ma7jq2s9xgoy" id="ma7jq2s9xgoy" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><div style="display: none;"';
var regex = /name=\"([^"]+)\"/g;
// that is, look for name=" literally, match anything but a double quote
// and store it in a group
var match = regex.exec(string);
alert(match[1]); //ma7jq2s9xgoy
```

See [a JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/w95Lf2L0/) and [a demo on regex101.com here](https://regex101.com/r/yQ0cL1/1). For the whole HTML document, consider using a parser instead though (jQuery? [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) ?)

Comment: Don't you think it kind of screams HTML, not a string?

Comment: @SterlingArcher: Indeed, it does. Have put a warning below :-)

Comment: im not sure what .exec is but thats not working..... the regex variable works great and is returning - **name="ma7jq2s9xgoy"**

Comment: now how do i get it to return only whats between the quotes?

Comment: @Matt "It's not working" is never a good comment. What exactly does not work?

Comment: .exec is not a function

Comment: Nevermind i got it by doing this

`var ker = String(regex).match(/"(.*?)"/g)`

`var ker = String(regex).replace(/"/g,"");`